# Stopping enumeration in JavaScript when using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, enumerable

I'm currently trying to get my head around using prototype in JavaScript.

To experiment with this, I've written a function that effectively works as allowing you to put a where clause onto arrays:

```
Array.prototype.where=(function(){
  var tmpArr=[],
      success;

  for (var x in this){
    var success=true;
    for (var i in arguments){
      if (this[x][arguments[i][0]]!=arguments[i][1]){
        success=false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (success==true){
      tmpArr.push(this[x]);
    }
  }
  return tmpArr;
});
```

An example use would be:

```
arrayName.where([0, 'Fred'], [1, 'Bloggs']);
```

For the sake of a test, this works pretty well. The only problem is if you were then to run

```
for (var x in someArrayHere){
  console.log(someArrayHere[x]);
}
```

You get the output the array, but with a record representing the function you've prototyped.

As far as I can work out, this is sorted by setting the function as non-enumerable, but I can't find any articles explaining how to stop it.

How would I go about it? Or would I have to do the below each time?

```
for (var x in someArray){
  if (typeof tSch[x]!="object"){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for...in` construct enumerates all properties of an object (and those inherited down the prototype chain). When you use it with an array, it will iterate over all properties of `Array.prototype`, as well as the elements of the array.

Use a normal `for` loop to prevent this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a shame =[

Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Note that you can work around this with `Object.hasOwnProperty` as mentioned in a couple of other answers. The reason I didn't mention that is that it's pretty bad practice. You probably just shouldn't use `for...in` with native objects!

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use the native `Array.prototype.forEach` method where available, and use a shim if not: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

Answer (score 1):

In general, using a `for ... in` loop to iterate through an array is bad practice.

However, a simple fix would be to use `Object.hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var x in someArray) {
  if (someArray.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    //...
  }
}
```

This is a more robust approach than your loop.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not mess with the prototypes of native Objects. This leads to problems - especially in combination with extern code/libraries.

Instead, you should make it a function that operates on an array parameter (for instance `function arrayWhere(arr)`).

If you want to stick to extending native prototypes, you should iterate over arrays with the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method (newer browsers, maybe add a fallback as described at the MDN), or the `hasOwnProperty` method of objects, as described [in this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Example%3a_Iterating_over_the_properties_of_an_object).